# <context:annotation-config> and <context:component-scan>

Tags: java, spring, annotations

In Spring 3 do I need to have `<context:annotation-config>` and `<context:component-scan>` defined in order to enable @PostConstruct?

*applicationContext.xml*

```
<context:component-scan base-package="net.test" />

........
...

<context:annotation-config />
```

I have a method getLazyLoad in my ManagedBean and I would like to use @PostConstruct for this bean.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your bean is not having any Annotations at class level related to `@Component`

```
<context:component-scan base-package="net.test" />
```

is not required.

To work with `@PostConstruct` only `<context:annotation-config />` is enough.

> EDIT1:

suspose If your bean is having any below annotation

```
@Component, @Repository, @Service, or @Controller.
```

then `<context:component-scan />` will scan those bean under specified package.

Comment: In order to scan packages do I still need `<context:component-scan base-package="net.test" />`?

Answer (score 3):

`<context:annotation-config>` is enough, after that you can instantiate your beans from context.xml and @PostConstruct, @Autowired, @Resource and some other annotations that Spring supports will be processed. Note if you use component-scan annotation-config mode is enabled by default.

Comment: In order to scan packages do I still need `<context:component-scan base-package="net.test" />`?